# can't get anything in param variable

Tags: jsp, servlets

I can't seem to get anything in param value...The request is passed to a servlet but the project stops at

http://localhost:8000/xweb/rimds?param=

tell me What i am doing  wrong

> JSp-

```
<%
out.println("<marquee bgcolor=\"cyan\">WELCOME TO XWEB</marquee>");
int x=(Integer)request.getAttribute("lasti");
//out.println(x);
for(int i=0;i<=x;i++)
{
    String msubject=(String)request.getAttribute("k"+i);
    out.println("<a href=\"/xweb/rimds?param=\""+msubject +">"+msubject+"</a>");
    out.println("</br>");
}


out.println("<a href=\"/xweb/customerLogin.html\">logout</a>");
```

%>

> Servlet-

```
String msubject=request.getParameter("param");
        String query="select * from inbox where msubject=? ";


        PreparedStatement pstmt=con.prepareStatement(query);
        pstmt.setString(1,msubject);        
        System.out.println(query);

        ResultSet rs=pstmt.executeQuery();



        if(rs.next())
        {
            String subject=rs.getString(2);
            String details=rs.getString(3);
            System.out.println(subject);
            System.out.println(details);
            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("rimdSuccess.jsp");

            rd.forward(request,response);
            ServletContext context=getServletContext();  



            context.setAttribute("s",subject);
            context.setAttribute("d",details);}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell me where are you setting the 'lasti' attribute and 'k'+i attributes ??

```
 int x=(Integer)request.getAttribute("lasti");

request.getAttribute("k"+i);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct Jsp:

```
<%
    out.println("<marquee bgcolor=\"cyan\">WELCOME TO XWEB</marquee>");
    Integer x=(Integer)request.getAttribute("lasti");
    int count =x;

    for(int i=0;i<=count;i++)
    {
        String msubject=(String)request.getAttribute("k"+i);
        out.println("<a href=\"/xweb/rimds?&param="+msubject +"\">"+msubject+"</a>");

        out.println("</br>");
    }


    out.println("<a href=\"/xweb/customerLogin.html\">logout</a>");
%>
```